# How do I add an Apps Script Library to AppMaker?

Tags: google-app-maker

I created this script to determine if the `Session.getScriptTimeZone()` would draw the time zone from the library file rather than AppMaker.  Here's the script:

```
function getFormattedDateString(dt,format){
  var format=format||"E MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm";
  var dt=dt||new Date();
  return Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dt), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), format);
}
```

I tested it in another script with the following code:

```
function test(){
  Logger.log(AMSLib.getFormattedDateString(new Date()));
}
```

I went into AppMaker and this dialog:

[image]

I've tried the Script ID from here:

[image]

I've also tried several deployment ID's from the publish from Manifest dialog and I keep getting the same answer:

[image]

I've also tried the Project Key which is used with other apps scripts to load libraries.

I don't know what to try next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, you need to publish your Apps Script app, after that it'll be assigned Script ID(by the way it can also be found in the published app URL). Once you have Script ID, you can specify it in App Maker and select library version you want to use:
[image: Add library]

To access library's functions you need to use name specified in the `object` setting:

```js
// Server side library call
var result = MyLibraryName.doSomeCoolStuff();
```

App Maker should be smart enough and pickup all library's public functions for autocomplete.

**Learn more:**

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries
https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/libraries

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by publishing my Apps Script App.  It's just a simple script.

Comment: When I try to refer Script ID of and library that was never published App Maker says me `No valid versions detected for this library`. Once I go to my library and `Publish -> Deploy as web app...` App Maker starts seeing library versions and allows to select one. Your library is not accessible for outer world until you publish it.

Comment: It's still not working for me but I'll keep working on it  but thanks for your help.

Comment: That's strange... the last thing that comes to my mind is permissions issue, maybe you created AM and AS apps under different accounts or in different domains or smth like this... Feel free to share your experience once you find the answers!

Answer (score 1):

That's really odd to not have a script key there. You might make a copy of your script, something might be corrupted. You can also get the key from the URL ex: https://script.google.com/a/ignitesynergy.com/d/**1oHnk_xl76KagGS4g7O2pC1MM4R3iZR8-7FlmzKXxRDtO1o5nDU2**/edit

Remember to File-> Manage Versions and create a version. You also need to set the sharing to public.

Comment: I'm sorry there was a script Id there.  I didn't think that publishing it here on SO was a good idea.  I probably should have just marked some of it out so it would look redacted.